# Difference between PAAS and cloud server.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, cloud, hosting

I am developing for a website that will need Scalability.Website using RoR. I am confused between Ninefold and DigitalOcean host. My website will be like Social networking website where I need to store lots of user data and media.

As a great developer suggest me-  digital ocean is a cloud server (configure your own database, web server ssh etc.), but ninefold is a platform as a service that you git push your code to.

I want to know exact meaning of this

Comment: Try making your way through Rails Tutorial that outlines the process of using Heroku. That will give you a good idea of what PaaS is. The simpler way would be to ask "that great developer".

Comment: @D-side : I really appreciate your answer. Thanks, I just wanted to know more about this topic that's why I Posted question on stackoverflow.Because stackoverflow have very great developers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in a short the difference goes like that.

There are two extremes of the offers on the market at the moment.

Digital Ocean, it creates you VMs, which then you need to config and manage yourself (meaning installing all the ruby, nginx and stuff)

and Heroku, which is completely abstracted, you don't have access to anything, you just push code to them and they run it somewhere on the cloud.

and then there is Ninefold, which is somewhere in between, they create you VMs, where you have access to and can specify things like disk size, number of CPUs and the size of RAM. But Ninefold also fully provisions the VMs for you, installs (and later updates) all the ruby, nginx, postgres and things like that. So, in the end it's kind of best of the both worlds, you can deploy code by just pushing it to GitHub, but you also have full access to VMs and can fine-tune them for your performance needs.

Ninefold also much more cost effective than Heroku when it comes to actual load.

Answer (score 1):

These are just different things for different purposes.

**A cloud server** is just a machine. It can do whatever you force it to do. Not essentially limited to hosting RoR or even any web platform in general. If you only want RoR, you have to set up Ruby, databases, install your app, configure proxies (if you want). You can also run supplementary stuff on that same machine (like, for an app using WebRTC you could also run STUN server there). You have to upgrade it regularly (and/or configure automatic upgrades) and respond to possible security flaws in the system under your app. Essentially the same as if you bought a physical server, hooked it to the network and used in production.

PaaS is a slightly different concept. For running your apps, you configure your machine, as said above: software, libraries, web server. You set up the platform for your app to run on. That is what P in PaaS is. On PaaS you are not in control of the OS and available software but you can be sure it is configured properly. You should only make sure that your app is configured properly. There is an idea of ["12 factors"](http://12factor.net) that describes the guidelines for building a PaaS-targeted app. That implies that PaaS is strictly single-purpose: it only runs processes based on your codebase without any commodities of a full-fledged system. Heroku, the most known PaaS, doesn't have a local database server, but your app will likely require it to function. So you can provide the URL of the remote database server for your app, which could be a service as well (DBaaS, Heroku offers that separately, in ClearDB addon for instance).

In fact, nothing's limiting you not to use both approaches. You could set up your server infrastructure in a way that doesn't depend too much on the system software. You can use Docker to separate the app's code, user data and required services (such as a database) from the rest of the system and each other. An app, when run as a Docker container, typically sits alone, has an exposed port and doesn't request much from the system. Database sits in its own container, which is linked to the app and discovered via environment variables, so the local DB server is not affected too. What good is that? Control. Everything is cleanly separated from the system and can be backed up, scaled or even migrated without recreating most of the apps' environments you previously had somewhere. Much like your own PaaS. It does require some knowledge of planning and setting up a platform and packaging your app for it. And it only makes sense if you want to run multiple apps.

Answer (score 0):

On Digital Ocean you would normally get an empty virtual box with a linux operating system of your choice. You ssh into that server, install rvm, install ruby, install nginx, install passenger or unicorn, install postgresql, set up capistrano on your local machine to deploy to that production environment you have on that server...

If Ninefold is anything similar to Heroku, it has been already configured for you. You just push your code and have your site running.

By Andrey Azov